# Is a martingale constant on the event that its quadratic variation is zero?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

Let $M_t$ be a continuous time martingale, and assume its quadratic variation is identically zero with some positive probability less than $1$.

To be more precise, assume there exists some event $E$ with $0 < \mathbb P(E) < 1$ such that for almost every $\omega \in E$, $\langle M, M\rangle_t (\omega) = 0$ for all $t \geq 0$.

**Question:** Does it follow that $M$ is almost surely constant in time on $E$? That is, $M_t = M_0$ for all $t > 0$ a.s. on $E$.

*Remark: For continuous martingales, this follows directly from  the Dambis-Dubins-Schwartz theorem.*

Comment: how about we use the Ito isometry for martingales

$$\operatorname{E}\left(\left(\int_0^t H_{s}\,dM_{s}\right)^2\right) = \operatorname{E}\left(\int_0^tH_{s}^2\,d[M]_{s}\right).$$

but for $H$ constantly equal to the indicator of $E$ at least in the case of E being measurable with respect to the filtration of M?

Comment: Oh damn, that works indeed..

Comment: @Thomas Kojar: Such an $H$ is not likely to be adapted.

Comment: @JohnDawkins I agree. Perhaps some conditional version might do the trick i.e. $H(t):=E[\chi_E|Ft]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, the following  Lengart's inequality is useful: (Please refer to
S. W. He *et al., Semimartingale Theory and Stochastic Calculus*, Sci. Press and CRC(1992), p.239, Theorem 9.23.)

**Theorem** Let $ X $ be an adapted cadlag process, dominated by an predictable process $ A $. Then for arbitrary constants $C>0, d>0$, stopping time $ T $ and measurable
set $ H $ we have
\begin{equation*}
    \mathsf{P}(H\cap [X^\ast_T\ge C])\le \frac{1}{C}\mathsf{E}[A_T\wedge d]+
    \mathsf{P}(H\cap [A_T\ge d]). \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
Hence for the continuous time  martingale $M$(if $ M $ is also a locally square integrable martingale), $M^2$ is dominated by its pridictable quadratic variation $ \langle M \rangle $. Using (1) for $ H=E $, it follows
\begin{align*}
    \mathsf{P}(E\cap [M^{\ast2}_T\ge C])&\le \frac{1}{C}\mathsf{E}[\langle M \rangle_T\wedge d]+
    \mathsf{P}(H\cap [\langle M \rangle_T\ge d])\\
    & = \frac{1}{C}\mathsf{E}[\langle M \rangle_T\wedge d] \le \frac{d}{C}, \quad 
    \forall C>0, d>0.
\end{align*}
Now let $d\downarrow0$ to get
\begin{equation*}
    \mathsf{P}(E\cap [M^{\ast2}_T\ge C])=0, \qquad \forall C>0. 
\end{equation*}
Further more letting $ C\downarrow 0 $ to get that $ M=0 $ almost surely on $ E $.

Comment: Hi, how do you obtain that $M^2$ is dominated by its predictable QV?

Comment: @Nate River Thank you for your question.   If $ M $ is a square integrable martingale, then $ M^2-\langle M\rangle $ is a local martingale and $\mathsf{E}[M^2_T]=\mathsf{E}[\langle M\rangle_T]  $ for every bounded stopping time $ T $.

Comment: Hmm, but I don’t see necessarily that this means that $M^2$ is a.s. dominated by $\langle M \rangle$. Sorry, I may be missing something obvious.

Comment: @NateRiver Pls refer to the book, mentioned above, p.238, Example 9.21.